# Binding two click events on one button with different attributes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, jquery-click-event

Anyway, I got this button that is supposed to open my nav.

**HAML:**

```
%button#nav-toggle{ :navigate => 'false' } Menu
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id='nav-toggle' navigate='false'>Menu</button>
```

And I'm binding two clicks on it like this:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#nav-toggle[navigate='false']").click(function(){
    console.log("opening nav");
    $("#nav-toggle").attr('navigate','true'); 
    
    $( "#masthead" ).animate({
        height:'100vh',
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      queue: false,
      done: function() {
        console.log("first done");  
      }
    }
    );
  });

  $("#nav-toggle[navigate='true']").click(function(){
    console.log("closing nav");
    $("#nav-toggle").attr('navigate','false'); 
    $( "#masthead" ).animate({
        height:'10vh',
    }, {
      duration: 1000, 
      queue: false,
      done: function() {
        console.log("second done"); 
      }
    }
    );
  });
});
```

For some reason, when I click the button for the second time (When its navigate-attribute is set to true, it still launches the first event of those two.

What am I missing here?

**Full code here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/virmasalo/pen/xOopQR?editors=1010)**

Comment: You can not bind an event to `$("#nav-toggle[navigate='true']")` because when the code is executed, no such element exists. You should bind the click event directly to the button (w/o attribute selector) and decide inside the click handler what you want to do (you can still get/set the attribute then).

Comment: you can bind single click and inside the function you can check for the attribute and do your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate the event.

Take a look at this
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAjkpA?editors=1010

You need to bind the event to a parent in this case the `.hamb-container`.

Here's a link to understand how delegation and event bubbling works https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

**Basically as a summary:**

When an event is triggered it bubbles the event all the way up to your root HTML tag.

That is good for when you want to add dynamic content or in your case pick out an attribute that changes dynamically.

So how do we bind to dynamic content? Simple. We surround them with a static container and bind to that instead. Additionally, we let JQuery know what the dynamic content will be. So Jquery will listen for an event on the static element and check if it actually originated from the element you were looking for.

**Something like this**

```
$( "#staticAncestor" ).on( "click", "#DynamicContent", function( event ) {

});
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Ok, this was even better and since you even put an polite ending on it, I'll accept this one :D Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to make sure you fundamentally understood why your code wasn't working rather than providing you an alternative. Cheers

Comment: Haha. Sure thing. But do look into event delegation. It has saved my life many times

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason, when I click the button for the second time (When its navigate-attribute is set to true, it still launches the first event of those two.
>
> What am I missing here guys and girls?

You missed nothing.

An event is bound to an element not to a property/attribute.

Because ***.click*** a shortcut for ***.on( "click", handler )***:

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler ): Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements

So, you can change your code like:

```js
$(function () {

  $("#nav-toggle[navigate='false']").click(function(){
    console.log("opening nav");

    var attr= ($("#nav-toggle").attr('navigate') == 'false' ? false : true);


    $("#nav-toggle").attr('navigate',!attr);

    if (!attr) {
      $( "#masthead" ).animate({
        height:'100vh',
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false,
        done: function() {
          console.log("first done");
        }
      }
                              );
    } else {
      $( "#masthead" ).animate({
        height:'10vh',
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false,
        done: function() {
          console.log("second done");
        }
      }
                              );
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='nav-toggle' navigate='false'>Menu</button>
```